# Не работает SQL запрос Update

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Проблема в том что не работает SQL запрос UPDATE. Вот сама таблица.[image]

Вот запрос:

```
myConnection3.Open();

string item = "redit";
int items_id = 3;

string query3 = string.Format("UPDATE items SET i_status = " + item + " WHERE items.id = "+items_id);

SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(query3, myConnection3);

SqlDataReader reader3 = command3.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: В языке SQL строки в запросе должны быть заключены в кавычки

Comment: И экранировать тоже полезно.

Comment: Остальные запросы ( Insert ) работают и так. Хотя я пробовал заключать в кавычки, не помогло.

Comment: "Остальные запросы ( Insert ) работают и так." - не работают, Вы чего-то не замечаете.

Comment: `command3.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никогда не собирайте запросы конкатенацией со строковыми переменными! Если еще не знаете что такое sql-инъекция, то просто подставьте в качестве значения `item`, ну например такую строку `"''; go; drop table  items; go;"`. Что-то мне подсказывает, что в реальном коде значение `item` будет приходить извне. Ну и опечатки с экранированием текста опять же.

Вместо этого лучше использовать параметризованный запрос:

```
myConnection3.Open();

string item = "redit";
int items_id = 3;

string query3 = string.Format("UPDATE items SET i_status = @item WHERE items.id = @itemId");

SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(query3, myConnection3);
command3.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1) = item;
command3.Parameters.Add("@itemId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = items_id;

command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Таким способом будет сгенерирован корректный запрос и ни каких вопросов с кавычками, экранированием и инъекциями. Тут подробно и с примерами: [Свойство SqlCommand.Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2)

`ExecuteReader()` может сработать, т.к. запрос не обязан возвращать хоть что-то, но если запрос заведомо не возвращает данные, а, например, только пишет в БД, то, для лучшей читаемости, стоит использовать `ExecuteNonQuery()`, который просто выполняет запрос и не ждет получения каких либо данных от сервера.

Что касается "Остальные запросы ( Insert ) работают и так", то вы ошибаетесь, кавычки `'<значение>'` обязательны для текстовых литералов в MS SQL (T-SQL). Возможно в других запросах значения приходят уже экранированными или где-то "глушатся" исключения, но в любом случае запрос с синтаксической ошибкой не может быть выполнен.

Comment: Если еще не знаете, что такое sql иньекции, то скоро узнаете  (.