# C# Windows form SQl, visual studio пытаюсь добавить данные в datagridview, но выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2015, c#-8.0

```
 public void MyExecuteNonQuery(string SqlText)
    {
        SqlConnection cn; // экземпляр класса типа SqlConnection
        SqlCommand cmd;

        // выделение памяти с инициализацией строки соединения с базой данных
        cn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
        cn.Open(); // открыть источник данных
        cmd = cn.CreateCommand(); // задать SQL-команду
        cmd.CommandText = SqlText; // задать командную строку
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // выполнить SQL-команду
        cn.Close(); // закрыть источник данных
    }
    private void FillSource()
    {
        string SqlText = "SELECT * FROM [Books]";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlText, ConnStr);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "[Books]");
        dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["[Books]"].DefaultView;
    }
    private void metroTile1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SqlText = "INSERT INTO [Books] ([Id],[Name],[Aftor],[Ganr],[Location]) VALUES (1, 'Name-01','Aftor-01','Ganr-01','Location-01')";
        frmAddEditBooks f = new frmAddEditBooks(); // создать экземпляр окна

        if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // сформировать SQL-строку
            SqlText = "INSERT INTO [Books] ([Name],[Aftor],[Ganr],[Location]) VALUES (";
            SqlText = SqlText + "\'" + f.txtName.Text + "\', ";
            SqlText = SqlText + "\'" + f.txtAftor.Text + "\', ";
            SqlText = SqlText + "\'" + f.cboJanr.Text + "\', ";
            SqlText = SqlText + "\'" + f.txtLocation.Text + "\')";

            // выполнить SQL-команду
            MyExecuteNonQuery(SqlText);
            // отобразить таблицу Source
            FillSource();
        }
    }
```

выдает ошибку System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: Посмотрите такой [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043980/222542), как лучше писать работу с БД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."

говорит о том, что данные, которые вы передаете в параметрах Insert имеют большую длину, чем задана для колонки в БД.

Не в даваясь в качество кода приведенного фрагмента, запредельную уязвимость для SQL-инъекций и прочее, вариантов у вас два:

1. (предпочтительный вариант) Посмотреть какой размер имеют колонки в базе и предварительно обрезать данные на клиенте. Например так:

   ```
   ... + f.txtName.Text.Substring(0,<размер колонки>) + ...
   ```
2. (нежелательный вариант) Оставить код как есть, а в базе задать колонкам максимальный размер - `varchar(max)|nvarchar(max)`, ну или совсем устаревший вариант - тип `text`.

---

Почитайте про параметризованные запросы, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/956695/198316) я уже писал об этом со ссылками на документацию, и никогда больше не собирайте SQL-запросы конкатенацией строк с использованием строковых переменных, значения которых задает пользователь.

Comment: Больше  Спасибо!!